# how to avoide duplication of threads?

Tags: android

I am newly joined android family.

I am implementing one thing related to handlers and threads.

When i am running my application one handler is created and run.

it is fine,but i am run my application another time,again
one more handler is created and run.

It increases duplication of handlers - how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Every `Application` in Android runs in its `own` `process`, so its not a big thing to worry about it. The `OS` would itself look after it. Also you can use stop the `Thread/Runnable` using `Handler` when you think its not necessary for it to keep running and its task is completed. You can have a look at [`Android Runtime`](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)

Comment: acthually what i am doing is.I am calling one brodcastreceiver class in every one minute through alarm manager.in brodcast receiver class i am clalling one hanler it is running.After one minute ones again brodcast receiver class will call through alarm manager.at that time one more handler is created.how i eleminate duplication of handlers.

Comment: calling broadcastreceiver, further what? this is not enough information. you should update your question rather.

Comment: the brodcasrreceiver class is call in every one minute.In side the brodcastreceiver class i am implementing one handler.After calling this class one more time one more handler is created.if u have any solution please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: You can make Handler static so it will be initialized only once.

Answer (score 0):

Every application will have `onCreate()` to run during launching and `onDestroy()` to run when you close the application. In the case of pausing (eg. pressing HOME button), it will run `onPause()` and `onResume()` upon resuming. You can make use of these function to ensure your threads get killed or closed properly. As an example:

```
boolean checkcondition = true;
Thread t = new Thread () {
    public void run() {
        while(checkcondition) {

        }
    }
};

public void onDestroy() {
    checkcondtion = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

this will cause all processes killed.

Comment: i am implementing handler in brodcastreceviers class.it does't have on destroy.